# Database design for theatre employees

Tags: database-design

I need to design database, that will be hold information about employees. They may be divided into several categories: actors, directors or musician. This categories may divided on some categories too. So, i have tree of employee categories. And i have performance table, that must have foreign key to director.

Can i make table, that hold common information about employee and have foreign key to table with categories tree? Would it be correct?

```
employee_categorie
+-----------------+----------+
|      name       | encoding |
+-----------------+----------+
| actor           | 1        |
| subactor1       | 1.1      |
| subactor2       | 1.2      |
| director        | 2        |
| first_director  | 2.1      |
| second_director | 2.2      |
+-----------------+----------+

employee
+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| employee_id | first_name | last_name | employee_categorie_id |
+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|           1 | Joshu      | Willis    | 1.1                   |
|           2 | Genry      | Ford      | 2.1                   |
|           3 | Jeff       | Bridge    | 1.2                   |
|           4 | Silvester  | Obama     | 2.2                   |
|           5 | Mark       | Watney    | 2.2                   |
+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+

performance
+----------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| performance_id | performance_name | performance_director_id |
+----------------+------------------+-------------------------+
|              1 | Godzilla         |                       5 |
|              2 | Alice            |                       4 |
|              3 | God is dead      |                       5 |
+----------------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what about cases where the director is also an actor? you don't want to keep a column for the category in the employee table, it's better to add another table to create a many to many relationship between category and employee.

Comment: Thanks, i know it, I have not included this table for simplicity. I'm more interested to know correct or not refer to table with tree.

Comment: Do you need to keep the list of employees relevant to a single performance? (the director, the actors, etc`)

Comment: Yes, i need keep list of employees for every performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, I suggest adding a table for performance_employees:

```
performance_employees
+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| performance_id | employee_id | category_id |
+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1              | 1           | 1.1         |
| 1              | 2           | 2.1         |
| 1              | 3           | 1.2         |
+----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

and in the performance table add a foreign key to this table for the actor. also, add check constraints to the performance table to make sure the director column actually points to a to a record where the category id points to a director.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand, why it is necessary to add a foreign key in performance for the actor to performance_employees and how it must looks like.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. it should be for the director, not for the actor.